# preposition: "on" treatment or "in" treatment?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is grammatically correct?

> John is **on** treatment for pneumonia.

or

> John is **in** treatment for pneumonia.

Answer (score 2):

.."in" is the closest but it still sounds clumsy.

"John is being treated for pneumonia"
or
"John is under treatment for pneumonia"